# Javascript timezone offset, date time

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I'm not quite certain that there is some kind of explanation or something but I have a problem regarding the timezone offset in javascript.

My time zone is +1 (Germany)

```
> new Date()
2019-12-04T17:58:30.626Z
```

I ran that code in my terminal in a node instance. And that I understand to some extent however my actual time was 18:58:30 at the time.

However when setting the time of the new Date to midnight. I clearly get the timestamp of midnight.

```
> new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
1575414000000
```

When however I use that to create a new timestamp than the output the time is 11pm of the previous day.

```
> new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
2019-12-03T23:00:00.000Z
```

Can someone explain why that is occurring and what reason it is for that to happen?

Comment: You are Setting the Time for your local time. check like this
var date = new Date(); date.toTimestring() and see its midnight for GMT+1:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours

> The `setHours()` method sets the hours for a specified date **according to local time**, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 **UTC** until the time represented by the updated Date instance.

Notice that the input of the method is interpreted as local time, but the output of the method is in UTC.  So when you run

```
new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

you do get a date object that represents midnight local time, which is equivalent to (in your case) 11pm the night before in UTC time (the `Z` at the end of the string indicates that it's in UTC time, or "Zulu" time.

Two options that might do more what you are expecting:

1. use `setUTCHours()` which will result in date object that represents midnight UTC time.
2. Convert it to a string in your local timezone, e.g.

   `new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toLocaleString()`

Comment: Thanks for answer #2. But do can you explain why `.setHours()` uses the local timezone offset?

Comment: That's just what it does.  I corrected the link to the setHours() documentation on MDN.  setHours() uses local time, setUTCHours() uses UTC time.